# Angular RXJS How to process multiple observables with one "fire and forget"?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I create a smart chain of observable processings where the function returns already after getting a result from the first observable? What I'm trying to do:

- The function `calculate` make some calculations and returns usually after 10msec
- The function `save` stores the data into a database but returns very slow, usually after 400-500msec

I would like now to call the function `process` and this function should return with the result of `calculate` immediately. However the `save` function has to be processed - something like fire and forget.

If I'm using the `forkJoin` the `process` returns when both functions are finished, but this isn't what I want to achieve. So I tried to the `merge` approach. But here I don't know which function returned.
What else can I do?

```
process():Observable:any{
    let x1 = this.calculate(...)
    let x2 = this.save(...)

    // TRY #1
    return forkJoin([x1, x2]).pipe(         // ca. 400msec
        map(res => {
            return res[0];
        })
    );


    // TRY #2
    return merge(x1, x2).pipe(              // ca. 10msec
        map(res => {
            // how to return only result of x1?
            return res;
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to include the save function in your observable stream if you don't want to subscribe to it (or want to forget this value)?

Comment: Because the `process` function is called from different places t makes sense to me to put the `save` here.

Comment: in case of #2 - use `filter`. But in worst case scenario, depending on how you are handing obs on the caller side, save might not be invoked at all / be aborted.

Answer (score 0):

So you want `save` to be done in the "bakground" if I understand correctly. If so, subscribe right away.

```
process():Observable<any>{
    this.save(...).subscribe(); // "fire and forget"
    return this.calculate(...)
```

or in case you are dealing with cold observables here

```
process():Observable<any>{
    return this.calculate(...).pipe(
       tap(()=>this.save(...).subscribe()); // "fire and forget only if you have had  subscribed to the main obs"
    )
```

Comment: this kind of "nested subscribe" is something I want to prevent...

Comment: @Lars there's no "nested subscribe", that's the right approach. Either call a subscribe outside of a pipe, or in a piped `tap`.

Comment: @MGX Thx! My "nested" was meaning that `process` is subscribed and inside `tap()` is a further subscribe. I thought or it would be nice to have just one `subscribe` on `process` obs

Comment: This is the way to do what you have asked for.

Comment: @Lars `tap` create side effects and is thought to make "fire & forget" calls (provided that you don't create memory leaks ofc). But I would say that the first approach is way cleaner IMO

Answer (score 0):

**[ignoreElements](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/ignoreElements) operator**

Ignores all items emitted by the source Observable and only passes calls of complete or error.

```
process() {
  let x1 = this.calculate(...);
  let x2 = this.save(...).pipe(ignoreElements());
  return merge(x1, x2);
}
```